# Creating M.ContentVersion from the WebClient SDK

Tags: content-hub

I am writing a job that reads from a JSON file and creates new M.Content items using the WebClient SDK. The ask is to create a new M.Content item if it doesn't already exist, otherwise create a new version of the existing M.Content item, so that there's a history of the incoming changes.

Creating a new version of an M.Content item is not seeming straightforward from the WebClient SDK. It looks like you could create a new M.ContentVersion entity programmatically, but M.ContentVersion has a required "Content" property that appears to be HTML generated by the Content Hub app code, which is a black box.

Is there any simple way to increment the version of an M.Content item through the SDK, and keep track of the previous values?